# PyQt QMessageBox crush program

Tags: python-3.x, qthread, pyqt5, qt-signals, qmessagebox

I have a problem with my code. How to correct the code below to QMessageBox not crash program? I don't know why this problem really exists. I tried run QMessageBox in new QThread but it changed nothing.

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Signals(QObject):
    update = pyqtSignal(int)
    enable_button = pyqtSignal(bool)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.button = QPushButton("Run", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onButton)

        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setTextVisible(False)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.progress)
        self.layout.addStretch()

        self.worker_thread = QThread()
        self.worker_thread.run =  self.worker
        self.worker_thread.should_close = False

        self.signals = Signals()
        self.signals.update.connect(self.progress.setValue)
        self.signals.enable_button.connect(self.button.setEnabled)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()
        self.resize(self.size().width(), 0)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.worker_thread.should_close = True
        self.worker_thread.wait()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onButton(self):
        self.button.setDisabled(True)
        self.worker_thread.start()

    def worker(self):
        for i in range(101):
            if self.worker_thread.should_close:
                break
            self.signals.update.emit(i)
            sleep(0.1)
        msgBox = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, "Ok", "Done.", QMessageBox.NoButton)
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/favicon.ico"), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        msgBox.setWindowIcon(icon)
        msgBox.addButton("Ok", QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
        msgBox.exec_()
        self.signals.enable_button.emit(True)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you show us any crash output? Apart from that it is not clear, why you  first select `QMessageBox.NoButton` and then later manually add the "Ok" button. You can use `QMessageBox::Ok` instead.

Comment: Why did you create a `QMessageBox` in a worker thread? The Qt GUI must run in the main thread. All widgets don't work in secondary threads. See [Threading Basics](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html).

Comment: Ok, I corrected issues identified by you, but it did not help. Could you provide me new idea? Please run this code in python so you can see what exactly happens, program freeze after display QMessageBox.

Comment: @Blumba. You did not correct the issues. As nymk said, you must not perform GUI operations outside the main thread.

Comment: @ekhumoro so what is correct way to call QMessageBox? Look at this.
http://pastebin.com/CFR0YeL2

Comment: @Blumba. Use a custom signal.

Comment: @ekhumoro custom signal? I don't know what you mean, could you give me a example how to use it?

Comment: @Blumba. Eh? You're already using them in your example (although I don't know why you put them in a separate class).